# Newrelic - Key transaction monitoring - geography based

Tags: newrelic

We would like to understand why performance from a particular geographical location is bad and  want to focus only on transactions from that location.

Is it possible to trace key transactions from a specific location ?

Francis

Answer (score 0):

You can see some geographical data about performance patterns using New Relic's Real User Monitoring (or RUM). This will let you see browser performance for various geographic settings. However, when New Relic monitors transactions within your web app, geographic data isn't generally present as a parameter on that transaction, meaning it's not possible to sort by geographic area with the standard instrumentation.

Depending on your agent version, you can add a parameter to a transaction or set a transaction's name, based on geographic area. Of course, this presumes that your app knows the region the request is coming from.

For the Java agent, my specialty, provided the region is available you could call `NewRelic.setTransactionName(String category, String transactionName)` early on in your transaction to name transactions based on region, then you can mark that transaction as a Key transaction to get separate alert thresholds for just that transaction.

Hope that helps, feel free to open a ticket with New Relic support if you'd like more detail.

Comment: Hi thanks for the explaination.  These transaction requests are coming from everywhere, and I don't understand why the agent should be instrumented, given that newrelic can calculate geographic data in RUM.  I will file a ticket for further discussions.